# Mostrar por medio de un array_push los valores que no pasan la validation en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array, session

disculpen, tengo un problema referente a un array_push. Ya que necesito mostrar por medio de un array_push los valores que no tienen las validaciones requeridas. Aquí les muestro el controlador.

public function UploadCodesFarmersStore(Request $request){

```
    $fields = [
        'category'=>'required',
        'tokens'=>'required',
        'account_info'=>'required',
        'type_payment'=>'required',
    ];

    $msj = [
        'category.required' => 'La categoría es requerida',
        'tokens.required' => 'El código es requerido',
        'account_info.required' => 'La información de cuenta para el pago es requerido',
        'type_payment.required' => 'El tipo de pago es requerido',
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $fields, $msj);

    $category = Category::where('to_sell', true)
        ->where('key_name', $request->category)
        ->first();

    if($category == null){
        toastr()->error('Ocurrio un error, esta categoria no esta permitida', '', ['timeOut' => 3000]);

        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    }

    
    $str_token = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n", " ", ","), "|", $request->tokens);
    $array_token = explode('|', $str_token);


    if(count($array_token) == 0){
        toastr()->error('No existe el código', '', ['timeOut' => 3000]);
        return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create');
    } 


     $codesArray = [];
    foreach ($array_token as $key => $code) {
        
        $array = array(
            'code' => $code,
            'uid_discord' => Auth::user()->uid_discord,
            'price' => $request->type_payment == 'USD' ? $category->price_token_farmer : $category->price_token_farmer_bs,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'operation_code' => $operation_code,
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($array, [
            'uid_discord'   => 'required',
            'code'   => 'required|unique:codes|min:21|max:21',
            'price' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required'
        ], [
            'code.unique' => 'Los códigos deben ser únicos',
            'code.min' => 'El mínimo de carácteres para cada código es de 21',
            'code.max' => 'El máximo de carácteres para cada código es de 21',
        ]);

        if ($key <= 10) {
              array_push($codesArray, $array_token);
            // array_push($array_token, $array);
            // Session::flash('test_hola', $array);
            // return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create')->withErrors($validator);
        }


        // if ($validator->fails()) {
        //     array_push($codesArray, $array);
            // Session::flash('test_hola', $array);
            // return redirect()->route('upload.codes.farmers.create')->withErrors($validator);
        // }else{
            // $model = Code::create($array);
            // $count = $count + 1;
        // }

        dd($array_token);

        if (!$validator->fails()) {
            // $model = Code::create($array);
            // $count = $count + 1;
        }

    }
```

}

y realmente no se como guardar esos valores que no tienen los requerimientos del validator, es decir, traerme los 'code' que son menores y mayores de 21 y que son repetidos, para poder mostrarlos en un $var_array por medio del array_push para que me los muestre por medio de un session flash, si pueden ayudarme por favor. Y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código está muy desordenado, por lo cual me limitaré a especificar la forma en que puedes filtrar un array (php nativo) o una colección (Laravel).

**Para filtrar un array en php nativo**

```
$elements = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$results = array_filter($elements, function($element){
    return $element > 3;
});
print_r($results);
```

**Para filtrar una colección**

```
$result= $your_collection->filter(function ($object){
                return $object->some_property < 10;
            });
```

Para ambos casos se recorrerán todos los elementos y te retornará solo los elementos que cumplen dicha condición, por lo cual, puedes hacer la negación de tu condición original para obtener todos los elementos que no cumplen.

Para utilizar variables declaradas en el contexto superior de la función anónima, puedes utilizar  `function($element) use ($min_val) {` (Aplica para la función anónima de php nativo y la de laravel)

ejemplo:

```
$min_val = 3;
$elements = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$results = array_filter($elements, function($element) use ($min_val){
    return $element > $min_val;
});
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio gracias. =) .

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, procura seleccionarla como mejor respuesta para ayudar a más personas en el futuro. éxito!